# How do you use multi-listeners in one method? (ANDROID)

Tags: android

how would I put the following to listeners into one method. So instead of having two listeners I can have one listener, that checks which checkbox was clicked.. thanksss

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.safe:
        if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
            ((CheckBox) view).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.tick);
        } else {
            ((CheckBox) view).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.black);
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `View.OnClickListener` and then you can have one method.

```
public class NameClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      switch(view.getId()) {
         case R.id.someWidget:
            // to do
         break;
         case R.id.anotherWidget:
            // to do
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

**Note:** Also one suggestion, try to have look also at `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   switch (buttonView.getId()) {
      case R.id.someButton:
         if (isChecked) {
            // some work
         }
         else {
            // some another work
         }
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: @AleksG thanks, under normal coditions i would recommend him to use `OnCheckedChangeListener` but he used `OnClickListener` so i added both approaches for sure and maybe for somebody else second approach can be useful.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0: I used your code, but now the 'tick' wont show up:( (code updatd).

Comment: you should use onCheckedChangeListener man, this is generally rocommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

implement the setOnClickListener in the current class ......

and

```
    private void mufListener() {
        muf = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.muf);

        muf.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void crewAreaListener() {
        crewArea = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.crewArea);
        crewArea.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



public void onClick(View view) {

                switch(view.getID()){

                case R.id.muf:
                case R.id.crewArea:
                if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                    ((CheckBox) view).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.tick);
                } else {
                    ((CheckBox) view).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.black);
                      }

                break;
             case R.id.tv2:
                    break;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ID in the listener:

```
private void setListeners() {
    final View muf = findViewById(R.id.muf);
    final View crewArea = findViewById(R.id.crewArea);

    OnclickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {
        @OVerride
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Checkbox ck = null;
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.muf: ck = muf; break;
                case R.id.crewArea: ck = crewArea; break;
            }

            if(ck == null)
                return;

            if (ck.isChecked()) {
                ck.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.tick);
            } else {
                ck.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.black);
            }
        }
    };

    muf.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    crewArea.setOnClickListener(ocl);
}
```